# Xcode 11.4 not generating custom intent class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Xcode 11.4 is not generating custom intent class. It works on Xcode 11.3.1. Didn't change any project config. Now getting "Use of undeclared type StartRecordingIntent" compile time error where StartRecording is the name of the intent. Any clue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: @Adam added code and screenshots

Answer (score 2):

Open the **File Inspector**, make sure to select "Public Intent Classes" of intent file *.intentdefinition.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by changing the build system from Legacy to New Build System. Can't explain the relation between the errors and the build system, but the errors are gone.
To change the build system go to File -> Workspace Settings -> Shared Workspace Settings and change from Legacy Build System to New Build System.

Comment: In fact there was a bug in Xcode 11.4 that prevented the generation of intents source files when building a project with Legacy build system. The bug was fixed by Apple on Xcode 11.4.1. Refer to Xcode 11.4.1 release notes for more information.